# Unload picture from shape on worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to add a picture and load an image in it on worksheet.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("Sample.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 100, 100)
    shp.Name = "MyPhoto"
End Sub
```

How can I unload the picture from the shape?
I tried these lines but none worked for me

```
Sub Unload_Picture()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes("MyPhoto")
    'shp.Picture = Nothing
    'shp.Picture = LoadPicture("")
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes("MyPhoto").Delete`

Comment: But I don't want to delete the shape. I just want to remove the picture loaded on it or load another picture. 
I doubt my first code doesn't create an image control. How can I create an image control on worksheet by the code?

Comment: How would you do this manually?

Comment: I didn't do that manually so I thought of vba code to do that for me :)

Comment: That seems backward to me. If you can't do this manually with a shape, how would you do it with VBA? But point aside, seems like you're going the image control route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add image control with vba

```
Sub ImageCTRL()
Dim Img As OLEObject, pic As MSForms.Image
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

With sh


    Set Img = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=20, Top:=20, Width:=400, Height:=400)
        
        
        With Img
        .Name = "MyImg"

Set pic = Img.Object
pic.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\yourpic.pdf Page 1 image 1.jpeg")
        
        
        End With
        End With
End Sub
```

To change the picture in the control.

```
    Sub changeImg()
Me.MyImg.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\otherpic.jpg")
End Sub
```

I have these codes in the worksheet module.

The image control has an autofit feature, check the cntrl properties window.

You can also resize the control to a specified size, same as when you added it.

```
    Sub changeImg()
Me.MyImg.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\newPic.jpeg")

With Me.MyImg
.Top = 20
.Left = 20
.Width = 400
.Height = 400
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. I need to fit the image control to be the same as the picture loaded or the vice versa. To fit the picture to the activex image control.

Comment: New added code...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't want to resize the width or height of the image control. I just want to fit the picture loaded to fill the whole image control. That what I meant (Sorry for confusion)

Comment: Did you not see I mentioned the control has an autofit?

Comment: So sorry, I didn't read well. I have used `.AutoSize = True` and worked well. Thank you very much for great help.

Comment: Last question I promise, what if I need to check if the activex image control `MyImg` exists or not?

Comment: I tried these lines and worked but I welcome any other idea `    Dim obj
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If obj.Name = "MyImg" Then MsgBox "Image Control Exists", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    Next obj
`